# Comparing results within a column and appending to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am doing a dummy project to hone my python skills and there is a problem I am encountering. I have a pandas column with many values inside it, I want to do the following (I have set chunksize = 1440 because I want to process the data in groups of 1440's and store the output for each group of 1440 separately.):

Take the first value of the column (let it be 'x')
Go through the remaining (1439) values, if you find a value greater than 'x' let it be 'y'.
If you find an entry whose value is 10 more than 'y' enter 'Profit' into a separate column. Or
If you find an entry whose value is 10 less than 'y' enter 'Loss' into a separate column.
This is what I have tried:

```
import pandas as pd
 
for df in pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Workstation/.spyder-py3/AAPL.USUSD_Candlestick_1_M_BID_14.11.2018-28.11.2020 (1).csv',chunksize=1440):
 
df = df[ df["Volume"] != 0]
 
df['Changing'] = ''
 
df.loc[(df.High.shift() - df.High).where(lambda x:x>3).dropna().index+1, 'Changing'] = "Profit"
 
df.loc[(df.High.shift() - df.High).where(lambda x:x<3).dropna().index+1, 'Changing'] = "Loss"
```

But I get the error:

```
'[960] not in index'
```

I think the loop does not stop when the column ends. Is there a way to fix this?

I know it's a lot, but any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Replace this

```
    lst= []
    
    for i in df['High']:
        lst.append(i)
```

with:

```
lst = df.High.to_list()
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am not sure how to proceed with the next steps

Comment: So you need complete script? :p

Comment: This is Time series data?

Comment: OK. your Goal is to identify big changing (upward and downward) ?

Comment: Yes, when one value crosses another value.

Comment: check my new answer.

Answer (score 0):

All values of df['High'] in a list

```
lst=list(df['High'])
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want?

when value > 3 than previous the `Changing` column appended `profit`, and when value < 3 than previous the `Changing` column appended `Loss`.

```python
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(199)
d = pd.DataFrame({"x" : np.random.randint(1,12, 10)})
d['Changing'] = ''
d.loc[(d.x.shift() - d.x).where(lambda x:x>3).dropna().index+1, 'Changing'] = "Profit"
d.loc[(d.x.shift() - d.x).where(lambda x:x<3).dropna().index+1, 'Changing'] = "Loss"
```

df:

```python
    x Changing
1   7         
2   1     Loss
3   8   Profit
4   3     Loss
5  11   Profit
6   9     Loss
7   3     Loss
8   6   Profit
9   3     Loss
```

Comment: `import pandas as pd
for df in pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Workstation/.spyderpy3/AAPL.USUSD_Candlestick_1_M_BID_14.11.2018-28.11.2020 (1).csv',chunksize=1440):
   df = df[ df["Volume"] != 0] #Just to remove redundant values
   lst=list(df['High'])
   x =lst[0]
   df_hi = pd.DataFrame({"x" : x})
   df_hi['Output'] = ''
   df.loc[(df.x.shift() - df.lst[0][0]).where(lambda x:x>10).dropna().index+1, 'Output'] ="Profit"
    df.loc[(df.x.shift() - df.lst[0][0]).where(lambda x:x<10).dropna().index+1, 'Output'] ="Loss"
    print(df_hi)`    
    '

Comment: I tried the above code(sorry for the bad formatting) it gave the error - 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'lst'. What is going wrong?

Comment: ```
for df in pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Workstation/.spyder-py3/AAPL.USUSD_Candlestick_1_M_BID_14.11.2018-28.11.2020 (1).csv',chunksize=1440):
    df = df[ df["Volume"] != 0]
    df['Changing'] = ''
    df.loc[(df.High.shift() - df.High).where(lambda x:x>3).dropna().index+1, 'Changing'] = "Profit"
    df.loc[(df.High.shift() - df.High).where(lambda x:x<3).dropna().index+1, 'Changing'] = "Loss"
```

Answer (score 0):

```python
for df in pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Workstation/.spyder-py3/AAPL.USUSD_Candlestick_1_M_BID_14.11.2018-28.11.2020 (1).csv',chunksize=1440):
    df = df[ df["Volume"] != 0]
    df['Changing'] = ''
    df.loc[(df.High.shift() - df.High).where(lambda x: x > 10).dropna().index+1, 'Changing'] = "Profit"
    df.loc[(df.High.shift() - df.High).where(lambda x: x < 10).dropna().index+1, 'Changing'] = "Loss"
```

Comment: Thank you so much. While running this the error - `'[960] not in index'` was shown. I think the loop does not stop when the column ends. Is there a way to fix this?